# PsExec: The user name or password is incorrect

Tags: windows, remote-access, psexec

I know there are similar questions to this. But none of them resolved my problem and asking it as a new question.

I tried psexec to remotely execute the following example code.

```
psexec \\192.168.1.70 -u PcName\RemoteUserName -p RemotePassword ipconfig
```

I checked the PcName and RemoteUserName very carefully in the target machine, and they are correct. My client uses "Windows 10 Enterprise", and target uses "Windows 8.1 Enterprise".

I have done the following things so far,

- Copied [PsExec v2.11](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) in "C:\Windows\System32" both client and
  target machines,
- Ran `"reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f"` in elevated
  command prompt in target machine,
- Firewall is switched off in both machines,
- No any connections between two machines except VNC viewer
  (tried psexec without VNC viewer as well).

But, I still get the following error. What am I doing wrong.

```
Couldn't access 192.168.1.70:
The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying hours, I found a mistake.

I changed the target machine's (Windows 8.1) username in '`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts\Change Your Name`'. But it has not changed the username associated with the command prompt.

Once I used the original user name which was shown in the command prompt as the `RemoteUserName` in `PsExec` command the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else coming across this question, the issue in my instance was the password had punctuation in it, which needed escaping when running against a batch file.

In the end I couldn't get the escaping to work reliably and changed the password to remove the punctuation that needed escaping.